# I want to fetch the data inside the span using the parent class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to fetch what is written inside the span where `class="select2-selection__rendered"` using the tr class `tr1` in jQuery. Thanks for helping!

## Code:

```
<tr class="tr1" id="1">
  <td>
    <select class="selUser select2-hidden-accessible" name="select[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="0">----Select Product----</option>
            <option value="Haris">Haris</option> 
            <option value="Hammad">Hammad</option> 
            <option value="Haroon">Haroon</option> 
            <option value="Haseeb">Haseeb</option> 
        </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 300px;">
        <span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-select-ht-container">
        <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-select-ht-container" title="Hammad">Hammad</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> 
    </td>
  <td><input class="price price1" type="text" value="0" disabled=""></td>
  <td><input class="quantity quantity1" id="1" type="number" value="1"></td>
  <td><div id="total1"></div></td>
  <td><div style="text-align:center; width:35px;"><button type="button" class="close" id="1"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></button></div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Clarify a bit please - Obviously we can just fetch directly from `$('.selection__rendered')` - you mention `tr1`. Why? will the span not have a class or something? Do you just mean this: `$('.tr1 .selection__rendered').text()`?

Comment: or, are you looking for the 4th child of the first child of tr1?

Comment: actuallly there are many other spans with the same class name select2-selection__rendered only the different is the tr class name that s why i want to fetch it through the tr class name

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$('tr.tr1 td span.select2-selection__rendered').text()
```

or even like this?

```
$('tr.tr1 td span.select2-selection__rendered').html()
```

Comment: thanks alot i was doing the same but with the complex method like tr.tr1 td span span span span.select2-selection__rendered that s why it was not working for me thanks alot

Comment: if this answered your question, could you mark it as Accepted?  Thanks!